# Aspose not detecting digits

Tags: c#, aspose

I cannot for the life of me get aspose to detect any digits, I've tried many different solutions but none seem to work.

Here is an example[image]

As you can see it doesnt look anything remotely right.

I've now got the code (which is on a timer, so that the feed is live):

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            Image img = Clipboard.GetImage();

            pictureBox1.Image = img;
            ocr.Config.ProcessColoredBackground = true;


            if (img != null)
            {
                var ms = new MemoryStream();


                img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp); // put here the image format 
                ms.Position = 0;

                ocr.Image = ImageStream.FromStream(ms, ImageStreamFormat.Bmp);
                ocr.Config.RemoveNonText = true;
                ocr.Config.Whitelist = new char[] { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '.' };



                    if (ocr.Process()) // Start processing it 
                {
                    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Text: " + ocr.Text;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yeh it hits the breakpoint. it looks like it's doing what its supposed to but it's just not converting the image (https://prnt.sc/hjkh7m)

Comment: mjwills, I'm not sure what you mean (sorry im a newbie at c#

Comment: on the form load

Comment: I've put it within the timer, and it's coming back with much better results besides for the number 1 and a decimal its not recognising. Why is declaring it in the timer bringing better results?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160545/discussion-between-bcltd-and-mjwills).

Comment: If I had to guess, the `OcrEngine` may not be designed to be reused the way you were before. By newing it up inside the function you may thus have sidestepped your original issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem, as it was mentioned, is white text on black background.
To be correctly recognized, such images must be inverted.
The problem will be resolved in future Aspose.OCR releases.

Answer (score 1):

Aspose.OCR APIs support Arial, Times New Roman, Courier New, Tahoma, Calibri and Verdana in Regular, Bold and Italic styles with black text color and white background. At the moment, Aspose.OCR has some issues with colorful backgrounds. Aspose team is working on this feature. You may try [Cloud version of Aspose.OCR](https://products.aspose.cloud/ocr/cloud).

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Comment: So that area would not be detected you think?

Comment: Yes, It will not be possible.

Comment: Yes, in case you have an image with black text color and white background then we can perform OCR operation on it. Furthermore Aspose.OCR APIs support Arial, Times New Roman, Courier New, Tahoma, Calibri and Verdana in Regular, Bold and Italic styles.

Comment: can you give example of how to invert colour and use ocr?

Comment: Using Aspose.OCR it is not possible to manipulate/change image. Aspose.OCR is an API that can be used to perform OCR operations. You may please visit the online documentation to explore it further:
https://docs.aspose.com/display/ocrnet/Home.